# Player Notifications with Xamarin MediaManager plugin

Tags: xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.forms

I'm using the media manager nuget plugin and it's great, but for the life of me, I can't get the lock screen or car bluetooth to show the notifications. I'm using the following to display the notifications (set within OnAppearing)

```
ViewModel.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            switch (e.PropertyName)
            {
                case "RadioSchedule":
                    if (listData != null)
                    {
                        listData.ItemsSource = null;
                        var first = ViewModel.RadioSchedule[0];
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        {
                            listData.ItemsSource = ViewModel.RadioSchedule;
                            MediaFile.Metadata.Artist = MediaFile.Metadata.DisplaySubtitle = MediaFile.Metadata.AlbumArtist = first.Artist;
                            MediaFile.Metadata.Title = MediaFile.Metadata.DisplayTitle = first.Track;
                            MediaFile.Metadata.DisplayIcon = new Image { Source = "icon".CorrectedImageSource() };
                            MediaFile.Metadata.BluetoothFolderType = "1";
                            MediaFile.Type = MediaFileType.Audio;
                            MediaFile.Url = Constants.RadioStream;
                            MediaFile.Availability = ResourceAvailability.Remote;
                            MediaFile.MetadataExtracted = true;
                            MediaFile.Metadata.Date = DateTime.Now;
                            MediaFile.Metadata.Duration = 300;
                            MediaFile.Metadata.Genre = "Rock";
                            MediaFile.Metadata.TrackNumber = MediaFile.Metadata.NumTracks = 1;
                            MediaFile.Metadata.DisplayDescription = "Radio Station";
                            if (!ViewModel.NotificationStarted)
                            {
                                if (CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaNotificationManager != null)
                                    CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaNotificationManager.StartNotification(MediaFile);
                                ViewModel.NotificationStarted = true;
                            }
                            CrossMediaManager.Current.MediaNotificationManager?.UpdateNotifications(MediaFile, MediaPlayerStatus.Playing);
                        });
                    }
                    break;
```

The code itself is being hit (I can set break points and they are hit). I've tried it on and off the UI thread as well.

The playlist comes from a webapi which works fine. The notifier gives unknown/unknown on the device media player (both iOS and Android) and nothing in-car. For Android, the permissions the readme file says to use have also been set.

Is there some sort of magic I have to do to get this to work? This is a Xam.Forms package rather than something native.

The MediaPlayer is started further in the class using the following code

```
CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(Constants.RadioStream, MediaFileType.Audio, ResourceAvailability.Remote);
```

Where Constants.RadioStream is the URL of the radio stream.

Comment: what is MediaFile?

Comment: Are you using PCL or shared project?

Comment: IMediaFile MediaFile and in a PCL

Comment: I see you are assigning its properties.How you create it?